# Ubuntu16 + tomcat8: WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common

Tags: tomcat8

I installed tomcat8 on Ubuntu 16 using 
   sudo apt install tomcat8
I only need one tomcat, no need for CATALINA_BASE.

But, I got warnings below. Can I ignore these warnings? Or anything I can do?
Any information would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Aug 07, 2016 8:01:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Aug 07, 2016 8:01:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Aug 07, 2016 8:01:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Aug 07, 2016 8:01:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Aug 07, 2016 8:01:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Aug 07, 2016 8:01:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
```

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: It seems some of your files are missing or the user executing tomcat doesn't have access. The Tomcat instance won't start without it.

Comment: These warnings are an annoyance but they don't prevent tomcat from starting.